# Scraping Web VBA Excel unclear

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I just started learning web scraping and I'm trying to make a code that Search for specific Data in Web page and click on search then Extract specific Data in excel sheet , I succeed to put the variable that I want to look for in the Web page but When I use the search button I receive this error [image]

I donno how to do it or to correct it
this is my code and Button code

VBA Code

```
     Sub clickICC()
     Dim ie As Object
     Dim form As Variant, button As Variant
     Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

     myjobtyp = InputBox("Enter type of MP,MOD,DATE")


      With ie
     .Visible = True
     .navigate ("http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")


     While ie.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
     Wend

     ie.document.getElementsbyname("searchById").Item.innertext = myjobtyp


    Set form = ie.document.getElementsbytagname("form")

     Set button = form(0).onsubmit
     form(0).submit

      Do While ie.busy: DoEvents: Loop
      Set TDelements = .documents.getElementsbytagname("td")
    r = 0
     c = 0

      For Each TDelements In TDelements
     sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(r, c).Value = TDelement.innertext
      r = r + 1
     Next





      End With
       Set ie = Nothing


      End Sub
```

the web button code

[image]

Anyone have a clue about this or light me on how fixing this  ?

Comment: Anyone Can help me ? :(

Comment: Obfuscating the webpage link is the main reason for your post not to have any answer.

Comment: What line is lighted when the error appears?

Comment: line with  " Set button = form(0).onsubmit" I think because my button ID search doesn't have an ID  so it's possible to change it with rowspan and colspan ??

Comment: Remove the line `Set button = form(0).onsubmit`. Share the URL of the webpage. Currently I can't reproduce the issue with that code, check [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry for the delay the problem you can't log to that site because it is local and confidential  the search button is without ID name "<Input name "" onclick="....."" So is there anyway to use the button function with rowSpan and colSpan ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a CSS selector to target the src string.

```
document.querySelector("input[src*=""/cmh/cmh/image/button_search.gif""]").Click
```

Note that there is a typo in your original post:

```
Set TDelements = .documents.getElementsbytagname("td")
```

There is no `s` on the end of `.document`.

Comment: Did you try this?